# PostgreSQL: SELECT MAX numeric value for entire table from multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table similar to this (3 rows, 4 columns: id, name, gradeA, gradeB):

```
id    name    gradeA    gradeB
------------------------------
1     David   59        78
2     Anna    66        92
3     David   22        89
```

I'm looking for a query that will give me 1 numeric property for the highest grade by in the whole table by condition.
for example:

> What is the highest grade for any student named David?

The answer should be  { maxGrade: 89 }

Note: grades are stored as varchar values and should be cast to numeric values for comparison

Comment: How come "_grades are stored as varchar values and should be cast to numeric values for comparison_"? I'd use int data type instead.

Comment: Thats a 'given'. I did not configure the table and they are 'natively' used as string values in other places.

Comment: above JSON is a filed in your table or you have a table with 4 fields

Comment: The above example reflects a table with 3 rows and 4 columns: id, name, gradeA, gradeB

Comment: "*grades are stored as varchar values*" - do you have a chance to fix that broken data model? ***Never*** store numbers as varchars. Just don't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to combine `max()` with `greatest()`

```
select max(greatest(gradea::int, gradeb::int)) as max_grade
from the_table
where name = 'David';
```

If you need a `JSON` result (because you wrote: *result should be {maxGrade: 89}*), you can wrap that query and convert the row to JSON:

```sql
select to_jsonb(t) 
from (
  select max(greatest(gradea::int, gradeb::int)) as "maxGrade"
  from the_table
  where name = 'David'
) t;
```

Comment: @user11350468 because without the max() you get two rows with. One with 89 and one with 78

Comment: Yes, Got it, I forgot about the duplicate names.., Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

We shall achieve with GREATEST and MAX:

1. We can make use of `GREATEST` to return the large value between the columns grade A and grade B for every user record
2. And use `MAX` to return the maximum grade if more than user matches with the same name.

```
SELECT 
  MAX(GREATEST(gradeA::integer, gradeB::integer)) as maxGrade 
FROM 
  "table_name" 
WHERE 
  "table_name"."name" = 'David';
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a lateral join:

```
select max(grade::int) as max_grade
from t cross join lateral
     (values (gradea), (gradeb)) v(grade)
where name = 'David';
```

In particular, this works if any of the grades are `NULL`.

It can also easily be tweaked to get *which* grade is the maximum:

```
select v.*
from t cross join lateral
     (values ('a', gradea), ('b', gradeb)) v(which, grade)
where name = 'David'
order by grade::int desc
limit 1
```

Comment: What would be the expected output of the 2nd 'which' query?

Comment: Why don't you run it to see?  It puts the name of the columns that has the maximum.